# 301 Redirecting: Joomla 1.5 to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I need to 301 redirect around 6000 URLs. I have already prepared and tested all the URLsand its working fine. But I'm facing only one problem.

Old URL to new URL redirection is working fine, for example:

```
Redirect 301 /career/old-url.html /career/new-url/1/
Redirect 301 /career/old-url2.html /career/new-url/2/
```

But when I add redirect category page URL to new category page URL, for example:

```
Redirect 301 /career /category/career/
Redirect 301 /career/old-url.html /career/new-url/1/
Redirect 301 /career/old-url2.html /career/new-url/2/
```

Then it breaks all URLs by adding "Category" word to the URLs, for example:

```
Redirect 301 /career/old-url.html /career/new-url/1/
```

Redirects to:

```
Redirect 301 /career/old-url.html /category/career/new-url/1/
```

Thus breaking all the URLs: If I won’t redirect that 47 Joomla category page URLs to New WordPress Category URLs then rest of 6000 URLs redirection works just fine.

I have 6000 articles URLs and 47 categories. So if I won’t redirect 47 categories then it will create 47, 404 pages. So I have only one question. What is the perfect code to redirect all the URLs along with the categories?

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess processes redirects in order, so you need to have the most specific redirect at the top and the most general at the bottom. Try this instead:

```
Redirect 301 /career/old-url.html /career/new-url/1/
Redirect 301 /career/old-url2.html /career/new-url/2/
Redirect 301 /career /category/career/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-category-url/

It simply removes /category/ from url.

Comment: Hello!

Thanks it worked.... As I use Wordpress SEO by Yoast it has option to remove the category.... Thanks again....